# BigQuery Update with Inner join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dml

Does it possible to do an UPDATE on a table based on a JOIN with an existing table in BigQuery?

No any doubles in this query

```sql
SELECT profile_id, count(*) as cnt 
FROM `instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.influence` 
GROUP BY profile_id HAVING cnt > 1
```

Also it works for

```sql
select a.profile_id, b.username
from  `instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.influence` AS a
inner join (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT profile_id, username 
FROM `instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.profile_id_lut`) AS b 
ON a.profile_id = b.profile_id
where a.username is null
```

Now i got only this problem
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

```sql
UPDATE
  `instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.influence` AS a
SET
  a.username = b.username
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT profile_id, username 
FROM `instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.profile_id_lut`) AS b
WHERE
  a.username IS NULL
  AND a.profile_id = b.profile_id
```

Comment: The error seems to indicate that there is more than one record in `profile_id_lut` that matches a given `profile_id` in `influence`.

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: OK, so how do you want to handle that use case? Maybe pick the maximu or minimum value from the available `username`s?

Comment: So, database has many rows with diffent usernames, but unique profile_id

`SELECT profile_id, count(*) as cnt
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT profile_id, username 
FROM instagram-tags-c67d8.sample_dataset.profile_id_lut
) b 
GROUP BY profile_id HAVING cnt > 1;`

Therefore, i think that best idea - is to delete older usernames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that there is more than one record in `profile_id_lut` that matches a given `profile_id` in table `influence`.

You have to decide how you want to handle that use case first. Possible options would include:

- delete duplicates records from source table `profile_id_lut`
- pick the maximum or minimum value from the available `username`s
- pick the username that has the maximum or minimum `profile_id`

The best choice depends on your functional use case and cannot be assessed from the information given in your question...